# MYSQL find max value from each department

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
employeeid | departmentid | bossid | name | salary
```

I need to find the max salary, but for each of the different departmentid's.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` with the aggregate function [`MAX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max):

```
SELECT MAX(salary), departmentid FROM your_table GROUP BY departmentid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `group by` clause to build a group around `departmentid`. For that group you can use aggregate functions to run operations on the data of each group, like `max()`

```
select departmentid,
       max(salary) as max_sal
from employees
group by departmentid
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`MAX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column.html) and [`Group By`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html):

```
SELECT DepartmentId, MAX(SALARY) AS Salary
FROM EmployeesTable
GROUP BY DepartmentId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select departmentid,  max(salary) as salary
from yourtab
group by departmentid
```